# MS SQL Server. Как отфильтровать таблицу со связью "многие ко многим"?

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы, со связью многие ко многим.

1. Первая таблица - Products,
2. Вторая таблица - Ingredients.
3. Третья таблица - ProductsIngredients

Products (ID, Name)
Ingredients (ID, Name)
ProductsIngredients (ID, ProductID, IngredientID)

Соответственно: продукты могут иметь много ингредиентов, и ингредиенты могут иметь множество продуктов в которые они входят.

Требуется получить из БД только те продукты, которые содержат, к примеру,
и молоко, и пшено, и сахар (причём порядок указания может быть хаотичным).
Как это сделать на стороне БД не понимаю, а тащить огромные таблицы в оперативную память и обрабатывать на стороне клиента - не вариант как мне кажется.

Прошу помощи, заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужен запрос, который вернет продукты, имеющие все 3 ингредиента:

```
select p.name
from Products p
    join ProductsIngredients pit on p.id = pit.ProductID
    join Ingredients i on i.id = pit.IngredientID
where i.name in ('Молоко', 'Сахар', 'Пшено')
group by p.name
having count(distinct i.id) = 3
```

Comment: Да, подходит, спасибо. Только поясните 1 момент, что делает последняя строчка.. Так как до остальных я и прежде догадался, но запрос из-за "in" выводил все продукты содержащие или молоко, или сахар, или пшено)

Comment: А, и ещё. Как вытащить Product целиком, не перечисляя после select что мне нужно вытащить?

Comment: @Nikita мы накладываем условие, чтобы у продукта было только 3 ингредиента - молоко, сахар и пшено, а потом смотрим, сколько из них уникальных. если уникальных все три, то тогда там есть и молоко, и сахар, и пшено, если 2 - то там не встретился 1 какой-то ингредиент. второй вам комментарий немного не понял)

Comment: по второму вопросу -  мне нужно получить не только имя продукта, но и все остальные поля (ID, Category, Description, ... их там много. Просто в вопросе указал только ID и Name для простоты). 
А здесь же мы получаем только Name (select p.name)..
Но если я пытаюсь сделать select p.* то мне выдаёт ошибку 'Column 'Products.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: @Nikita если вам нужны остальные поля только из таблицы Products, то напишите их через запятую, и все поля добавьте в `group by`. Либо оберните запрос в подзапрос и присоедините к нему снова таблицу products, там уже можно с p.*